# conditionally pop-up a message using XML

Tags: xml, xsd

I fall into a scenario where I have to check a condition if that is true then I need to pop-up a message when ever user click on the concerned button.

I will not be able to paste the whole XML here so will paste the relevant piece of XML.

```
XML -

<var name="arg_lock_visible">
    <select><![CDATA[select case when has_action_access('Lock') = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end from dual]]></select>
</var>
    <arg name="arg_nb_entities" from="data_space" value="ds_selected_entities" />

<actions_template name="check_action_promote_demote">
            <set_data_space name="ds_selected_entities" value="0" />

            <for_each ref="dw_promote" from="all">
                <if>
                    <condition>
                        <expression>
                            if(:arg_promote=:var_action_promote, if(:promote_check='Y',1,0),
                            if(:arg_promote=:var_action_lock, if(:lock_check='Y',1,0),
                            if(:arg_promote=:var_action_demote, if(:demote_check='Y',1,0),
                            if(:arg_promote=:var_action_unlock, if(:unlock_check='Y',1,0),0))))
                        </expression>
                    </condition>
                    <then>
                        <set_data_space name="ds_selected_entities">
                            <expression>:ds_selected_entities + 1</expression>
                        </set_data_space>
                    </then>
                </if>
            </for_each>
            <if>
                <condition>
                    <expression>
                        if (:ds_selected_entities=0, 1, 0)
                    </expression>
                </condition>
                <then>
                    <information_message>:arg_msg_no_action</information_message>
                </then>
            </if>
        </actions_template>

<button label="Lock" icon="lock.png" label_visible="true" button_style="true">
                                    <visible>
                                        <expression>:arg_lock_visible</expression>
                                    </visible>
                                    <set_local_value name="arg_promote" ref="var_action_lock" />
                                    <set_local_value name="arg_msg" value="Please add a comment to explain the lock." />
                                    <set_local_value name="arg_msg_no_action" value="You must select at least one entity to lock." />
                                    <run_actions_template template="check_action_promote_demote" />
                                    <set_local_value name="arg_title">
                                                               <expression>'Lock (' + string(:arg_nb_entities) + if         (:arg_nb_entities = 1, ' entity)', ' entities)')</expression>
                                        <arg name="arg_nb_entities" from="data_space" value="ds_selected_entities"></arg>
                                    </set_local_value>

                                    <run_actions_template template="action_promote_demote" />
                                </button>
```

Here in this XML I need to add the same condition in template "check_action_promote_demote" as

```
<if>
            <condition>
                <expression>
                    if (:ds_selected_entities=0, 1, 0)
                </expression>
            </condition>
            <then>
                <information_message>:arg_msg_no_action</information_message>
            </then>
        </if>
```

above code is responsible for showing message

```
<set_local_value name="arg_msg_no_action" value="You must select at least one entity to lock." />
```

In same manner I need to add one more condition here or say IF ELSE block in template for which I have a SQL which returns 0 or 1 based on the parameters passed to it so when the output of the SQL is "N" then it should show another message "Please select valid entity".

I have changed the XML to below but it is not working :(

```
    <var name="arg_lock_visible">
    <select><![CDATA[select case when has_action_access('Lock') = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end from dual]]></select>
</var>
    <var name="arg_promote_visible">
            <select><![CDATA[select 0 from dual]]></select>
        </var>
    <arg name="arg_nb_entities" from="data_space" value="ds_selected_entities" />

    <actions_template name="check_action_promote_demote">
                <set_data_space name="ds_selected_entities" value="0" />

                <for_each ref="dw_promote" from="all">
                    <if>
                        <condition>
                            <expression>
                                if(:arg_promote=:var_action_promote, if(:promote_check='Y',1,0),
                                if(:arg_promote=:var_action_lock, if(:lock_check='Y',1,0),
                                if(:arg_promote=:var_action_demote, if(:demote_check='Y',1,0),
                                if(:arg_promote=:var_action_unlock, if(:unlock_check='Y',1,0),0))))
                            </expression>
                        </condition>
                        <then>
                            <set_data_space name="ds_selected_entities">
                                <expression>:ds_selected_entities + 1</expression>
                            </set_data_space>
                        </then>
                    </if>
                </for_each>
                <if>
                    <condition>
                        <expression>
                            if (:ds_selected_entities=0, 1, 0)
                        </expression>
                    </condition>
                    <then>
                        <information_message>:arg_msg_no_action</information_message>
                    </then>
                </if>
                <if>
                    <condition>
                        <expression>
                            if (:ds_selected_entities=0, 1, 0)
                        </expression>
                    </condition>
                    <then>
                        <information_message>:arg_msg_no_action</information_message>
                    </then>
                </if>
                <if>
                    <condition>
                        <expression>
                            if (:test_arg=0, 1, 0)
                        </expression>
                    </condition>
                    <then>
                        <information_message>:arg_msg_no_lock</information_message>
                    </then>
                </if>
            </actions_template>

    <button label="Lock" icon="lock.png" label_visible="true" button_style="true">
                                        <visible>
                                            <expression>:arg_lock_visible</expression>
                                        </visible>
                                        <set_local_value name="arg_promote" ref="var_action_lock" />
                                        <set_local_value name="arg_msg" value="Please add a comment to explain the lock." />
                                        <set_local_value name="arg_msg_no_action" value="You must select at least one entity to lock." />
                                        <set_local_value name="arg_msg_no_lock" value="All entities are not at level 3." />
                                        <run_actions_template template="check_action_promote_demote" />
                                        <set_local_value name="arg_title">
                                            <expression>'Lock (' + string(:arg_nb_entities) + if(:arg_nb_entities = 1, ' entity)', ' entities)')</expression>
                                            <arg name="arg_nb_entities" from="data_space" value="ds_selected_entities"></arg>
                                        </set_local_value>

                                        <run_actions_template template="action_promote_demote" />
                                    </button>
```

I am not much familiar with XML so not able to figure out where should I make changes to satisfy the requirement. 
please ask for more information if required.

Any help would be appreciable !

Comment: I don't think this is an XML question. I think it's a question about whatever is using this XML. It doesn't look familiar; what framework, tool, language, etc. is using the XML?

Comment: Hi Daniel,
I am not sure about what  framework, tool, language like Java HTML etc. is using this XML as I majorly work on Oracle DB and within our team no one is also familiar with XML's.
But when I make changes in this XML then I have to replace modified XML on a WAS server and then restart the services to reflect the changes on the web page of the application.

Comment: I am getting below error while try to run a SQL with parameter in XML which is mentioning JAVA in it.


 at com.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
 at com.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: com.core.data.dao.sheet.vo.model.dependency.exception.MissingVariableDefinitionException: A variable/argument with name arg_promotion_level is missing in your sheet definition.
 at com.core.data.dao.sheet.vo.model.dependency.DependenciesGraphModel.findNode(DependenciesGraphModel.java:571)